# Tensorflow Keras LSTM with sequence_loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq

I'm building a simple LSTM model with `tensorflow.keras` and would like to use `sequence_loss` but it's not working with my current setup.

My input is always 4 words and the target is shifted by 1 word:
`[w1, w2, w3, w4] -> [w2, w3, w4, w5]`

I know that sequence_loss takes a weight argument, so I had to write a wrapper around it to make it work in keras, but I'm having problem aligning the shape of the matrices.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, 
                    output_dim=embed_size,
                    weights=[embedding_matrix],
                    trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True, activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax"))

def seq_loss_fn(logits, targets):
    all_ones = tf.ones([batch_size, 4])
    return tfa.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, targets, all_ones)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss=seq_loss_fn, metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])


Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 4, 100)            55400     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 4, 100)            80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 4, 554)            55954     
=================================================================
Total params: 191,754
Trainable params: 136,354
Non-trainable params: 55,400
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have tried it without `softmax` activation as well but the following is the error:

```
    loss=seq_loss_fn)
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 373, in compile
    self._compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics()
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1653, in _compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1713, in _prepare_total_loss
    per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py", line 221, in call
    return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
  File "train_rnnlm_tom2.py", line 120, in seq_loss_fn
    return tfa.seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, targets, all_ones)
  File "/Users/tom/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/loss.py", line 90, in sequence_loss
    raise ValueError("Logits must be a "
ValueError: Logits must be a [batch_size x sequence_length x logits] tensor
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error, `seq_loss` take a `[batch_size, sequence length, logits]` sized 3D array. You are producing a `2D` array of size `[batch_size, logits]`. In order to correct this, simply set,

```
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
```

and probably need to change `all_ones` to,

```
all_ones = tf.ones([batch_size, 4, 1])
```

**PS**: I hope you have a good reason for changing `LSTM` activation. Because LSTMs don't behave the same way when changing activation as compared to feed forward layers. LSTM gradients specifically depend on the behavior of the activation in order to ensure a good gradient flow.

Comment: I added `return_sequences=True` (didn't add the 3rd dimension) and I was able to compile it, but I still get the same error when I start training. If I add the 3rd dimension in `all_ones`, I get error when I compile the model.